# How to fix leak at bottom of double hung vinyl window

Tags: windows, leaks

Window leaks during driving rain at corners of the front lip of the bottom sash track.  During rains, water flows into the end corners of the bottom track and out the weep holes. However, when the rain is very heavy, even though I have cleaned the weep holes, it backs up in the track and flows over the front lip of the track, at the tack corners, into the house.  Would drilling 2 holes in the back of the track divert enough water out the back window, preventing water from rising over the front track and into the house?

Comment: A photo of the area you're describing would be a big help here.

Answer (score 1):

In lighter rains the weep holes work properly and in heavier rains they back up. So it seems they are functioning and just not able to keep up at times.

It sounds like you need to enlarge the weep holes or add more of them.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer.  A window repair company suggested he place a couple of holes on the back of the track (rail) to allow water rising in the track to be diverted to the back of the window and not into the house. I have 26 windows and only 4 leaks like this. The windows are 25 yrs old.

Comment: HI Kyle,  The pocket sill cannot be popped out, so I will attempt to place a narrow nozzle, attached to my garden hose, into the side holes of the sill pocket and gently wash out the remaining debris in the chamber. If an extra weep hole is still needed a could use a Dremel to carve out a new weep hole and add a weep hole cover with a hinge. Is there a way I could also test whether the window seal needs replacement? Thank you for your clear precise advice and your kindness to me!

Comment: @718KW if you'll take the [tour], you'll see that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up arrow next to any answer that helps you and the check mark next to the answer that helps you the most.